# Fix BS4 module not found error in Pycharm Mac OS

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pycharm

as wondering if somebody can help me because I can't find anything on the internet that works. When I do import BS4 it tells me module not found in pycharm
if I do pip import bs4 or pip3 install bs4 it tells me that is already installed. attaching picture for further details. thank you in advanced. see picture in link https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb6q9.png

Comment: Normally you do "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup" - have a look at BS4 documentation: - https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/intro-to-beautiful-soup

Comment: Looks like you're using a virtual environment; have you ran `pip install bs4` in the virtual environment yet?

Answer (score 0):

Please check that beautiful soup is presented in `File - Settings - Project - Python Interpreter`, if not follow these steps: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#install-package

Comment: thank you. the key was on venv. I ran pip install bs4 globally and then when create my virtual environment I just inherit it. not sure how to ran pip install within the venv though. thank u